# VBScript — Cut substring from page source by regexp

Tags: regex, vbscript

I get a page code, that (among other) consists of pieces like this:

```
 marker.server = '81.30.178.138';
 marker.number = '001-999-141';
 marker.token = 'b402e62ca6934e00919045e1da2f0fb9';
```

Is there a way to cut IP and token to two String vars, finding them by identical middle thing - marker.number?
I'm not good neither in VBS nor in it's regexp things... Please help.

Comment: Did you mean that you want just extract the IP adress ??

Comment: Влад, рекомендую [*Stack Overflow на русском*](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you want to extract the IP adress, take a look at this code :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,Data
Title = "IP Public Adress"
Data = "marker.server = '81.30.178.138';"&_
"marker.number = '001-999-141';"&_
"marker.token = 'b402e62ca6934e00919045e1da2f0fb9';"

MsgBox "My IP Public Adress is : " & vbCr & Extract_IP_Public(Data),64,Title
'**************************************************************
Function Extract_IP_Public(Data)
    Dim objRegex,Match,Matches
    Set objRegex = new RegExp
    objRegex.Pattern = "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b"
    objRegex.Global = False
    objRegex.IgnoreCase = True
    Set Matches = objRegex.Execute(Data)
    For Each Match in Matches   
        Extract_IP_Public = Match.Value
    Next
End Function
'**************************************************************
```